# Remove objects from a stream which are already in a database in a reactive manner

Tags: java, java-stream, reactive-programming, flux, spring-webflux

I'm scanning a directory for files, then processing the results. I want to remove files from the result of the scan that I already have in a datastore before further processing.

Trying to do this in a reactive fashion, using reactive mongodb. I'm just unsure how to implement a filter in such a manner as to use the result of a database query.

```
@Override
public Flux<File> findFiles(Directory directory) {

    // Only get these file types as we can't process anything else
    final Predicate<Path> extensions = path ->
            path.toString().endsWith(".txt") ||
                    path.toString().endsWith(".doc") ||
                    path.toString().endsWith(".pdf");

    final Set<File> files = fileService.findAll(Paths.get(directory.getPath()), extensions);

    final Stream<Video> fileStream = files
            .stream()
            .map(this::convertFileToDocument)

            // This is wrong (doesn't compile for a start), but how do I do something similar or of this nature? 
            .filter(file -> fileRepository.findById(file.getId()));

    return Flux.fromStream(fileStream);
}
```

`convertFileToDocument` just maps the file to a POJO, nothing fun happening there.

How can I go about adding the filter based on the result of the `findById`, or is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `fileRepository.findById` returns a Mono, I would recommend you convert the stream to a flux and then filter using `filterWhen`; checking if the Mono has an element. Something like

```
final Stream<Video> fileStream = files
        .stream()
        .map(this::convertFileToDocument);
return Flux.fromStream(fileStream).filterWhen(file -> fileRepository.findById(file.getId()).hasElement().map(b -> !b));
```

This will filter out all files that return a non-empty Mono for `findById`, or exist in the database. If I misunderstood something, please let me know.

Comment: I think this is almost correct, I just need to reverse it... I want to remove all the elements from the `fileStream` that are in the database. From what I can tell, this is still processing elements that exist in the database already. Unless I've implemented something incorrectly.

Comment: I have changed my answer to invert the Mono<Boolean> from `hasElement` so it filters out all files already in the database

Comment: Champion that nailed it. Thanks heaps!